# Changing ip address of apache server using php

Tags: php, linux, apache, ip

I am trying to create a settings page(for the clients) where in they can view the current up address,change the ip address etc. I have a php file to view the ip address

```
 <?php
  $res=shell_exec("ifconfig");
  echo $res;
 ?>
```

This code works just fine and displays the expected result. 
However the code to change the ip address of the server is not working properly.

```
 <?php
 shell_exec("ifconfig eth0 192.168.163.136");
 ?>
```

After running this code when i check the ipaddress on the terminal using ipaddr i don't see any change in the ipaddress. 
Pls point out where i am going wrong. I think its a problem of apache not being a super/root user. If that is the case i don't know how to make apache run as a root user.

Comment: possible duplicate of [change ip address of server using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271921/change-ip-address-of-server-using-php)

Comment: Your Intentions are unclear wtf are you trying to do!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `/srv/http` before ifconfig worked. All it needed was the root owned location.

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP script doesn't have enough privileges to change the interface address. You may want to write a Shellscript, give it the right privileges (e.g., change its owner to root, and set the suid bit), then run it from your PHP script. Yet, I advise against doing such thing

Comment: ok so can u give me more details on how to set the suid bit. Any link? Thanks

Comment: Sure. Check if [this blog post](http://nixshell.wordpress.com/2007/04/21/suid-shell-scripts-setting-the-sticky-bit/) helps. Also be sure to read the first link the author provides ([Why suid shell scripts are a very bad idea](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part4/section-7.html)). Another way would be giving _sudo_ privileges to the user that runs your script, which is even an *worse idea* - it could do a lot of damage!

Answer (score 1):

IP address are configured in *Network Layer* of an Network Protocol, not in **application layer** where PHP runs. *Simply*, PHP does not have access to it and cannot changed them.

Just imagine the vulnerabilities it could create if this was possible.

Comment: _Any code_ running on a server can change the IP address on the server provided it has given enough rights. Usually the PHP / Apache server doesn't have those, but can be given to them (although from a security standpoint not overly wise). Changing an IP address would however most probably break the current HTTP connection to the dropped IP.

Comment: OK i understand that it is not a wise move but still i would like to know how to get the rights for apache to run that particular script

Comment: @apurvnerlekar, You are not getting the point, if somehow you are able to change the IP, you will not be do anything, because the active connection will already be disconnected.

Comment: @apurvnerlekar, If you insist on doing this, there seems to be previous queustion asked with an working solution. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8272395/295264)

Comment: I dont think I have said anything incorrect. Why the downvote?