# Proxy server in php

Tags: php, proxy, ip, server

I'm using proxy server extension in firefox to change my IP address.

Is there any scripts in php to change the ip-address? I found only domain changing scripts in php but not ip related scripts. Any suggestions please.

Comment: Please check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271921/change-ip-address-of-server-using-php

Answer (score 0):

Using curl, you can do that... Try below one:

```
    <?php

         $proxy = "xx.xx.xx.xx:xx";
         $proxy = explode(':', $proxy);
         $url = "http://www.google.com";

         $ch = curl_init();
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy[0]);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy[1]);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
         $exec = curl_exec($ch);

  ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I didn't understand how to use it. Can you pleaseexplain. In `$proxy` i put my proxy ip address then i run the script. To check ip address I put `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` it displays my ip instead of proxy.