# How to execute shell script using php?

Tags: php, shell, asterisk

I try to monitor the call in Asterisk.

If I want to listen event I must start service with this command and I store bash file in there /etc/rc.d/init.d/asterisk_ipu_gui.bash

```
service asterisk_ipu_gui start
```

And the I login Asterisk CLI, and check the status with these command

```
asterisk -vvvr
manager show connected
```

Ex show in picture:

[image]

If It has IP address 127.0.0.0 ---> start service success.

This is manual, now I want to use PHP execute that shell script. How can I make this?

I write my code like this, but it not affect.

```
<?php
 $output1 = shell_exec('service asterisk_ipu_gui start');
 $output2 = shell_exec('asterisk -vvvr');
 $output3 = shell_exec('manager show connected');
echo "<pre>$output3</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Does $output1 or $output2 show anything?

Comment: No, it not show any thing

Comment: You may try /usr/bin/service instead of service

Comment: Thanks let me try.

Comment: Is your shell_exec function enabled? try to output shell_exec('ls'); or if(function_exists('shell_exec'))

Comment: I am assuming you would have to issue a command for what you require from Asterisk in the same command as when you login. Your logged in instance may not be available any more by the time you issue your `manager show connected` command.

Comment: apparently, from your image, when you run `asterisk -vvvr` you're entering its server, and PHP can only execute commands at the same level of the server running the code

Comment: It not work but I store /etc/rc.d/init.d/asterisk_ipu_gui.bash in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It issues the command in the same command as the login as I mentioned in my comment above:

```
 $output1 = shell_exec('service asterisk_ipu_gui start');
 $output2 = shell_exec('asterisk -vvvr "manager show connected"');
```

`$output2` should hold your expected results now.

Also, try to add your www-data user to asterisk group, this may be due to permissions and ownership issues. If you can do it locally with 127.0.0.1, that means your local user is allowed to do it and it works, but when php tried via www-data, it fails.

Comment: It not work. I store bash file in /etc/rc.d/init.d/asterisk_ipu_gui.bash

Comment: Yes, maybe. In manual I am a root user. But in php Imaybe I am not. So how I fix it?

Comment: try this from command line, this will add apache user to asterisk group: `sudo usermod -a -G asterisk www-data`. Then run your php script.

Comment: Shell response: www-data does not exits

Comment: if I use adduser www-data asterisk, so which mode I should use? -b, -c, -d,...?

Comment: You cannot use `adduser` as that command is to create a new user. You are supposed to be assigning an existing user to an existing group, what is wrong executing the command as I supplied it?

Comment: If I use "sudo usermod -a -G asterisk www-data" shell response "-bash:sudo: command not found". Then If I use " usermod -a -G asterisk www-data" --> shell response "www-data does not exits"

Comment: which user and group own your web root directory, i.e /var/www and everything inside it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135621/discussion-between-nistelrooy41001662-and-coderodour).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having php execute each shell command, try putting all commands in a shell script and then execute that script with php.

you can have commands in asterisk.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
service asterisk_ipu_gui start
asterisk -vvvr
manager show connected
```

now execute that with php:

```
<?php 
$output = shell_exec('/home/user/scripts/asterisk.sh'); 
echo "$output"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put echo after every command

```
<?php
$output1 = shell_exec('service asterisk_ipu_gui start');
echo "<pre>$output1</pre>";
$output2 = shell_exec('asterisk -vvvr');
echo "<pre>$output2</pre>";
$output3 = shell_exec('manager show connected');
echo "<pre>$output3</pre>";
?>
```

Also look into [manual](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.shell-exec.php), espessially into User Contributed Notes

Answer (score 0):

If your php has root permission to access asterisk then it should work

Also instead of

```
 $output2 = shell_exec('asterisk -vvvr');
 $output3 = shell_exec('manager show connected');
```

try

```
$output2 = shell_exec('asterisk -rx "manager show connected"');
```

[The simplest way to control Asterisk from an external shell](http://the-asterisk-book.com/1.6/asterisk-rx.html)

Comment: Important problem is $output1 = shell_exec('service asterisk_ipu_gui start'); not work via PHP. I sick with this.

Comment: Try giving the full path like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202887/why-php-command-execservice-apache2-restart-doest-work-on-ubuntu